# Stringify array inside an object

Tags: javascript, json

Can someone explain why JSON.stringify output is different from item1 and item2 objects.

```
var item1 = {
    name: '',
    childItems: [],
    addChild: function (name) {
        var child = Object.create(item1);
        child.name = name;
        this.childItems.push(child);
    }
};

var item2 = {
    name: '',
    addChild: function (name) {
        var child = Object.create(item2);
        child.name = name;
        if (this.childItems === undefined){
            this.childItems = [];
        }
        this.childItems.push(child);
    }
};
```

Stringifying objects

```
var root = Object.create(item1);
root.name = 'root';
root.addChild('child');
console.log(JSON.stringify(root)); //{"name":"root"}

root = Object.create(item2);
root.name = 'root';
root.addChild('child');
console.log(JSON.stringify(root)); //{"name":"root","childItems":[{"name":"child"}]}
```

The latter is the result I am looking for, but I can not figure out why the item1 not working?

Comment: `childItems` in the first example belongs to the object in the prototype, whereas in the second you create one with the current instance.

Comment: Thank you Sirko. Is there more elegant way of creating an object than item2??  I would not like to test if the array is undefined.

Comment: I'd use a constructor to add the instance properties and just leave the methods to be on the prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is in using `Object.create()`

```
var root = Object.create(item1);
```

creates a root object, which has item1 as prototype. In that case, `childItems` is part of the prototype. In addChild function

```
addChild: function (name) {
    var child = Object.create(item1);
    child.name = name;
    this.childItems.push(child);
}
```

since this is root, and childItems is not defined in root, it is searched in the prototype chain. Since item1 is its prototype, and it has childItems defined, that's where you're adding the item.

The same goes for item2, but with one exception: in your `addChild` function

```
if (this.childItems === undefined){
     this.childItems = [];
}
this.childItems.push(child);
```

this line `this.childItems = [];` creates an array childItems in the object root, hiding the childItems defined in the prototype you set when you used `Object.create(item2)`. That's why you see in the second `console.log(root)` the item added.

the line `this.childItems === undefined` also gives undefined (allowing the array to be created) because is not part of your prototype in item2.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo. So the main problem is that I am adding the  child objects into item1, not root.

Answer (score 0):

As [Sirko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169798/sirko) said:

> `childItems` in the first example belongs to the object in the
>   prototype, whereas in the second you create one with the current
>   instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this strings of code:

```
 if (this.childItems === undefined){
      this.childItems = [];
 }
```

In item1 childItems property is undefined but you try add item to it `this.childItems.push(child);`

In item2 you assign array to childItems property:

```
if (this.childItems === undefined){
     this.childItems = [];
}
```

So your code must be look like this:

```
var item1 = {
    name: '',
    childItems: [],
    addChild: function (name) {
        var child = Object.create(item1);
        child.name = name;
        this.childItems = [];
        this.childItems.push(child);
    }
};

var item2 = {
    name: '',
    addChild: function (name) {
        var child = Object.create(item2);
        child.name = name;
        this.childItems = [];
        this.childItems.push(child);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help!

Not sure if this the most elegant solution but this is what I came up with and it seems to work.

```
var item = {
    name: '',
    childItems: [],
    addChild: function (name) {
        var child = Object.create(item);
        child.name = name;
        child.childItems = [];
        this.childItems.push(child);
    }
};

item.name = 'root';
item.addChild('child1');
item.childItems[0].addChild('child2');
console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
//{"name":"root","childItems":[{"name":"child1","childItems":[{"name":"child2","childItems":[]}]}]}
```